# @jit changes the result of function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am speeding up computation for a function with a loop using `numba.jit` compiler. But I see that if I use the function without `@jit`, I get the correct answer, which is two `float32` numbers, but if I use `@jit` or even `@jit('UniTuple(float32, 2)(float32, float32)', nopython=True)`, I get `float`type numbers type result which has more precision than it should. The result for the first number should be `-0.0125`.

How can I fix this so that I have exactly the correct number? And why is it different with `@jit` and without?

```
gE = np.array([-0.0125], dtype=np.float32)
gP = np.array([0.01533981], dtype=np.float32)
@jit('UniTuple(float32, 2)(float32, float32)', nopython=True)
def findEP(TE, TP):
    E, P = 0,0
    delR = 999
    for i, (e, p) in enumerate (zip(gE, gP)):
        temp = np.sqrt( (TE - e )**2 + (TP - p )**2)
        if (temp < delR):
            delR = temp
            E, P = e, p
    return E, P
findEP(-0.0125, 0.01533981)
(-0.012500000186264515, 0.015339810401201248)
```

and without the @jit for the same function:

```
gE = np.array([-0.0125], dtype=np.float32)
gP = np.array([0.01533981], dtype=np.float32)
#@jit('UniTuple(float32, 2)(float32, float32)', nopython=True)
def findEP(TE, TP):
    E, P = 0,0
    delR = 999
    for i, (e, p) in enumerate (zip(gE, gP)):
        temp = np.sqrt( (TE - e )**2 + (TP - p )**2)
        if (temp < delR):
            delR = temp
            E, P = e, p
    return E, P
findEP(-0.0125, 0.01533981)
(-0.0125, 0.01533981)
```

Comment: That's floating point inaccuracy (not more precision); `-0.0125` in single precision is stored as (approximately ;-)) `-0.012500000186264514923095703125`

Comment: please provide a minimal working example. What is `gE` and `gP` ?

Comment: See e.g. https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: @Moritz Edited, working example

Comment: @Bart Why can't I force jit to give me the same precision, `float32`?

Comment: Can you try your second example with e.g. `np.array([-0.0125], dtype=np.float32)` (for both arrays)? Now you are creating double precision arrays, which makes the comparison unfair.

Comment: @Bart Sorry you are right, my original problem did have float32 array. Edited the code with correct dtype. The only way to 'fix' the problem is to do: `return np.float16(E), np.float32(P)`. But why is it different with `@jit` and without?

Comment: I think you might also be fooled by the `print()` of a Numpy array/type. Your first version returns a normal Python `float`, the second a `numpy.float32`. If I cast the latter to a normal Python float the printed results from both functions are identical.

Comment: Okay. I don't like this inconsistency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170086/discussion-between-bart-and-user7867665).